# ROS setup.bash issue, how to copy ROS workspace correctly

Tags: ros

I am new to ROS, now I am taking over one old ROS workspace which is really disordered, it is almost impossilbe for me to fix all compile errors in short time, so I created one new ROS workspace, then copy some related packages(folders) from old ROS workspace to my new workspace as a baseline. then I did below steps:
1, source /opt/ros/$version/setup.bash
2, then echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. --it is so good, only /opt/ros/$version some built-in packages are involved in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

### 3，in my new workspace/devel, run source setup.bash. --now something I am not sure/understand happens

after step #3, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH included ROS build-in pacakge, old workspace and my new workspace, and when I type 'catkin build $nodename' in my new workspace, some dependencies from old workspace involved
and still causing issue. my way of copying ROS node is OK or not? what is proper way to create my subset workspace. really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

It is related to `workspace overlaying`. Here it goes an official reference: (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying)

**Why does it happen?**

The thing is that, as @JWCS mentioned, you might have the old workspace in your `~/.bashrc` file at the moment you have **compiled** the `new_workspace`. (Check item **3** of the reference: *Chaining catkin workspaces*)

How to get rid of it?

Even if you remove it from `~/.bashrc` it will keep appearing on `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, because you have **compiled** your `new_workspace` with the `old_workspace` on the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

The **compilation** process takes the current $ROS_PACKAEGE_PATH into account and "attach" it to the workspace you are compiling.

**Solution**

- Go to your `new_workspace`: `cd ~/new_workspace`
- Remove `build` and `devel` folders: `rm -rf build devel`
- Source only the ROS installation folder: `source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash`
- Check your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, it will contain only the ROS distro installation path
- Recompile your new workspace: `catkin_make`
- Source your new workspace: `source ~/new_workspace/devel/setup.bash`
- Check your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, it will contain `/opt/ros/<distro>` + `new_workspace`

**About ~/.bashrc**

You can keep the `old_workspace` source, since you have the `new_workspace` source just after that. It will not consider the `old` anymore. But for the sake of simplicity and organization, I recommend you to keep in your `.bashrc` file only the workspaces you are working on.

Hope it can help you!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check. First of all, make sure that you're not sourcing the old repo in your ~/.bashrc. It's common practice to `source /opt/ros/VERSION/setup.bash` in the bashrc, and when you only have one workspace, to also `source ~/MY_WS/devel/setup.bash`. 
Second, if you already sourced the old workspace, you should just close the terminal before sourcing the new one, otherwise the old one will show up.

As for your method, of cleaning up a workspace, that's a good method. I would start moving one package at a time from the old workspace to the new one, and building everything each time. If you look at the package CMakeLists.txt/package.xml, all the dependencies should be listed. Make sure, if they're from the old workspace, that you copy them over. That should reduce your problems. If there is a package that is truly broken, you'll be able to find and isolate it quickly.

Comment: The critical part of Marco's answer, that I repeat here for emphasis, is to delete the old `build/` and `devel/` folders before recompiling, now with "`$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` contains `/opt/ros/<distro>` + `new_workspace`"

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by JWCS, the best thing you can do is to move one package at a time from the old workspace to the new workspace and recompile it every time, and verify if your CMakelist is the same as the old one. 
As for the third step I will use catkin_make to compile the packages.